# I want to hide a field in the derived class in jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a parent class,

```
Class A {
  @XmlElement(required = true)
  protected String name;
}
```

and a child class,

```
Class B extends A {

  @XmlTransient
  public String getName() {
     return name
  }
```

This is not hiding the property name when the object B is serialized.

Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: How can the name be _required_ for class `A` but not for class `B` when `B` is a subclass of `A`?

Answer (score 1):

JAXB doesn't allow to override the binding defined in parent elements in the children class.

To achieve you try to do I can propose to use a intermediary class which should contain all which is actually contained in your A class but you should  annotate it with `XmlTransient` and don't specify any mapping inside it.
Both class `A` and class `B` should extend this base class but each one may now define how to define their JAXB binding.

Here is an example starting from your code.

**Base class**

```
@XmlTransient
public class Base {

    protected String name;

    public String getName( ) {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The `A` class may use the default jaxb behavior if it is suitable. It will create a mapping with public fields and public getter/setter (therefore  inheritable from the parent class).

> By default, if @XmlAccessorType on a package is absent, then the
>   following package level annotation is assumed.
>
> @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)

**A Class**

```
@XmlRootElement
public class A extends Base {
}
```

If you want to specify attribute as `required` or use any specificities in the elements mapping, you should use explicit binding in the A class.

But the `B` class should specify  `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` in order to have a full control about fields to serialize/deserialize from the `Base` class.

**B Class**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class B extends Base {
    @XmlElement
    private String boundedStringSpecificToB;
}
```